# Using Excel VB to change imported data from Access colour coded accordingly

Tags: excel, macros, vba

What I'm trying to do is change specific range cells to specific colours.
It works that When there is an increase and when it is more than -2.00% that it should be red. However, when it is decreasing from the previous time it should be green, and once it is below -2.00% it should go black again.

So basically The cell with data in starts at C2 and ends at H54.
It works in a row format where like C2 is the main then D2 is continue data, etc. C3 is a new main data and D3 is the continue of that data, etc.

My code that I have been testing but not getting right is as follows:

```
Range("C2").Select
If Range("C2").Value >= "-2.00%" Then
With Selection.Font
.Color = -16776961
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Range("C2").Value < "-2.00%" Then
With Selection.Font
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

Range("D2").Select
If Range("D2").Value <= "-2.00%" & Range("C2").Value Then
With Selection.Font
.Color = -11489280
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Range("D2").Value > "-2.00%" & Range("C2").Value Then
With Selection.Font
.Color = -16776961
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Range("D2").Value < "-2.00%" Then
With Selection.Font
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If

Range("E2").Select
If Range("E2").Value <= "-2.00%" & Range("D2").Value Then
With Selection.Font
.Color = -11489280
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Range("E2").Value > "-2.00%" & Range("D2").Value Then
With Selection.Font
.Color = -16776961
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Range("E2").Value < "-2.00%" Then
With Selection.Font
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
```

However, when it goes to below 2.00% it still is green, and same error stays even when it increase again...

I will appreciate any assistance in getting this done asap... If you know of a shorter method please put it down for me to test it out.
Thank you very much for taking the time to review this.

Here is a sample picture of the result and what it actually should be:
[image]

Comment: Put together some redacted sample data together with expected results. It seems that [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula may be a better solution.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I added a sample. Though I do not want to do the conditional formatting approach as I need to do it by a button click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to follow your business logic as I perceive it from the code and sample image(s).

```
Sub ject()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, vRTRNs As Variant, thrshld As Double

    thrshld = 0.02

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 2).Offset(1, 2)
                .Cells.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                vRTRNs = .Value2
                For r = LBound(vRTRNs, 1) To UBound(vRTRNs, 1)

                    'deal with the first value
                    If vRTRNs(r, LBound(vRTRNs, 2)) >= thrshld Then
                        .Cells(r, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                    End If

                    'the remainder of the columns in the row
                    For c = LBound(vRTRNs, 2) + 1 To UBound(vRTRNs, 2)
                        Select Case vRTRNs(r, c)
                            Case Is >= thrshld
                                .Cells(r, c).Font.Color = _
                                    IIf(vRTRNs(r, c) >= vRTRNs(r, c - 1), vbRed, vbGreen)
                            Case Is < thrshld
                                .Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                        End Select
                    Next c
                Next r
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Results:

[image: returns_business_logic]

Comment: DUDE YOU ARE THE BOMB!! lol thank you so so very much... I accidently did my sample incorrectly and had it show positive formatted information... However, the percentages are negative, I just had to change your coding so that it will read as negative formats and also had to change the bigger as (>) and smaller as (<), but this worked great... Really thank you again so much

Comment: Hey Jeeped, Sorry to ask you this, but would you maybe look at another issue of mine, the link for it is: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155637/excel-vb-find-and-move-row-to-bottom-of-list-separate-with-new-heading) Please would you look at it, because I believe you would be able to help me with it :)