# Excel VB, find and move row to bottom of list separate with new heading

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to get the result that I want to get with my code which is as follows:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
With Worksheets("Data").Select
    With Range("A11:H11").Select
         With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            With Selection.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
                With Range("E11").Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Seasonal Items"
                    With Selection
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = False
                        With Selection
                            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                            .WrapText = False
                            .Orientation = 0
                            .AddIndent = False
                            .IndentLevel = 0
                            .ShrinkToFit = False
                            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                            .MergeCells = False
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
With Worksheets("Data").Select
    With Range("B2").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="fan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        With Selection
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            With Selection
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("12:12").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
                With Range("B2").Select
                Cells.Find(What:="fan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlAll, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                    With Selection
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
                        With Selection
                        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
With Worksheets("Data").Select
    With Range("B2").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="fan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        With Selection
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            With Selection
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("12:12").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
                With Range("B2").Select
                Cells.Find(What:="fan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlAll, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                    With Selection
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
                        With Selection
                        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
With Worksheets("Data").Select
    With Range("B2").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="fan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        With Selection
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            With Selection
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("12:12").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
                With Range("B2").Select
                Cells.Find(What:="fan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlAll, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                    With Selection
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
                        With Selection
                        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
With Worksheets("Data").Select
    With Range("B2").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Heater", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        With Selection
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            With Selection
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("12:12").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
                With Range("B2").Select
                Cells.Find(What:="Heater", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlAll, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
                    With Selection
                    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
                        With Selection
                        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

This code is not very elegant nor is it flowing really.

What I would like it to do is automatically search for specific wording in the column B which is either Fan or Heater, then move it to the bottom, where it is separated with a row that states season items.

See the picture below of the result:

[image]

Why I want it different is due to that the stuff is flowing and changing at points... It would make it simpler and I also would like the code to be much shorter and not for me to each time physically having to check and edit the code before running it...

Thank you for taking the time to view this and if possible provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will move the rows the way you want them, but you will need to add in the specific formatting yourself.

```
Sub test()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lrow2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow + 1, 5).Value = "Seasonal Items"

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
For i = 2 To lRow
lrow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If InStr(.Cells(i, 2), "Fan") > 0 Or InStr(.Cells(i, 2), "Heater") > 0 Then

.Rows(lrow2 & ":" & lrow2).Value = .Rows(i & ":" & i).Value
.Rows(i & ":" & i).ClearContents

End If

Next i

For i = 2 To lrow2

If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then

.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

End If

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response... Didn't check yesterday again if someone responded. Thank you for this, I will test it out and let you know of how I found it to work... Understood of the formatting I'll see to maybe try and repeat the format of a previous input... I'll give you a up vote for providing me with something to work with :D

Comment: Tested it out, and it did not move the rows, but I'm still busy going through the code to see if I might be missing something...